# Created a delete function for a list, but not all checked items are deleting

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I am currently taking Wes Boros JS 30 challenge and for this particular class, we created a list where we add foods we like. As an extra assignment, we are to create a `select` all function, an `unselect` all function, and a `delete` function.  I was able to successfully create a `select` all function where once you click that button, it selects all the items on the current list. My issue is that the delete function I created deletes everything, except for one or two items. Those undeleted items still remain checked, but I have to click on the delete button again in order for it to delete. FYI: I local storage was incorporated in this exercise.

Can somebody help me out and also explain what I was doing wrong?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/1ty45srL/16/) of it as well

Here is how I have my HTML set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LocalStorage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>LOCAL TAPAS</h2>
    <p></p>
    <ul class="plates">
      <li>Loading Tapas...</li>
    </ul>
    <form class="add-items">
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Name" required>
      <input type="submit" value="+ Add Item">
    </form>
    <input type="button" onclick="selectAll()" value="Select All"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="UnSelectAll()" value="Unselect All"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="deleteItem()" value="delete Item"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
  const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items');
  const itemsList = document.querySelector('.plates');
  const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
  
  
  
  //DELETE FUNCTION
  function deleteItem(){
      var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
      var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
      for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
        box = boxes[i];
        txt = texts[i];
        if(box.checked){
          box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
          txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
        }
      }
       
  }


  //SELECT ALL FUNCTION
  function selectAll(){
    var checkedItem = document.getElementsByName('item');
      for (var i = 0; i < checkedItem.length; i++) {
        if (checkedItem[i].type == 'checkbox')
            checkedItem[i].checked = true;
      }
  }
  
  //UNSELECT ALL FUNCTION
  function UnSelectAll(){
    var checkedItem = document.getElementsByName('item');
      for (var i = 0; i < checkedItem.length; i++) {
        if (checkedItem[i].type == 'checkbox')
            checkedItem[i].checked = false;
      }
  }

  //ADD ITEM FUNCTIO
  function addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    const text = (this.querySelector('[name=item]')).value;

    const item = {
      text,
      done: false
    };
    items.push(item); 
    populateList(items, itemsList);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    this.reset();
  }
//DISPLAY THE HTML FUNCTION
function populateList(plates =[], platesList) {
  platesList.innerHTML = plates.map((plate, i) => {
    return `
      <li>
      <input class="chk" type="checkbox" name="item" data-index=${i} id="item${i}" ${plate.done ? 'checked' : ''} /> 
      <label class="txt" name="item" for="item${i}">${plate.text}</label>
      </li>
    `
}).join('');
}

function toggleDone(e){

 if(!e.target.matches('input')) return; 
 const el = e.target;
 const index = el.dataset.index;
 items[index].done = !items[index].done;
 localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
 populateList(items, itemsList);
}
addItems.addEventListener('submit', addItem)
itemsList.addEventListener('click', toggleDone)
populateList(items, itemsList);


//DELETE ITEM EVENT HANDLER
itemsList.addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your delete function wasn't working properly it's because [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) returns a live `NodeList` which means when you use `removeChild` on each element in the collection the other elements gets rearranged and the length of list get's smaller causing you to skip some of them so you should convert your html collection to an array using `Array.from`

```
function deleteItem(){
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chk');
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
arrbox  = Array.from(boxes)
arrtext = Array.from(texts)
for(var i = 0; i < arrbox.length; i++){
var box = arrbox[i];
var txt = arrtext[i]; 
        if(box.checked){
          box.parentNode.removeChild(box);
          txt.parentNode.removeChild(txt);
        }
      }           
  }
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/s82rpnhu/)